# Access Other Projects Firestore Data in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firestore to build chat between multiple projects using this [Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects)
i.e. I have 2 applications / Firebase Projects.
App A and App B 
Now I have implemented simple collection in Firestore of App A, it works fine without any issues.
My problem is when I want to access Firestore of App A from App B using the above documentation 
I am getting error **Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions**
I have attached image of  collection [image: collection]
Rules are

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if true;
      }
  }
}
```

The Code I am using to configure on **ChatViewController** of App B is as follows

```
let secondaryOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "1:27992087142:ios:2a4732a34787067a",
                                   gcmSenderID: "27992087142")
secondaryOptions.apiKey = "AIzaSyBicqfAZPvMgC7NZkjayUEsrepxuXzZDsk"
secondaryOptions.projectID = "projectid-12345"
secondaryOptions.bundleID = "com.google.firebase.devrel.FiroptionConfiguration"
secondaryOptions.databaseURL = "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"

guard let secondary = FirebaseApp.app(name: "secondary")
else { assert(false, "Could not retrieve secondary app") }

// Retrieve a Real Time Database client configured against a specific app.
let _ = Database.database(app: secondary)

var collectionReference:CollectionReference?
collectionReference =
        Firestore.firestore().collection("eclinic").document("1002").collection("chats")

collectionReference?.order(by: "timestamp", descending: false).addSnapshotListener { [self] (snapShot, err) in
        if let error = err {
            print("Error     \(error)")
        }else{
            
            guard let snapDoc = snapShot?.documents else {
                print("Return  ")
                return
            }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure those rules are set on the project of app A where the data lives?  Security rules only apply to the one project where they are deployed, not to other projects.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes I am using firestore of App A where my data lives, Please suggest what should i do to access that from App B

Answer (score 0):

Exploring this documentation [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) I was able to get over my problem, the code is as follows

```
let secondaryOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "1:27992087142:ios:2a4732a34787067a",
                                gcmSenderID: "27992087142")
secondaryOptions.apiKey = "AIzaSyBicqfAZPvMgC7NZkjayUEsrepxuXzZDsk"
secondaryOptions.projectID = "projectid-12345"
secondaryOptions.bundleID = "com.google.firebase.devrel.FiroptionConfiguration"
secondaryOptions.databaseURL = "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"

FirebaseApp.configure(name: "secondary", options: secondaryOptions)

// Retrieve a Real Time Database client configured against a specific app.
guard let secondary = FirebaseApp.app(name: "secondary")
     else { assert(false, "Could not retrieve secondary app") }

let firestoreSecondary = Firestore.firestore(app: secondary)
var collectionReference:CollectionReference?
collectionReference =
firestoreSecondary.collection("eclinic").document("1002").collection("chats")

collectionReference?.order(by: "timestamp", descending: false).addSnapshotListener { [self] (snapShot, err) in
     if let error = err {
         print("Error     \(error)")
     }else{
         
         guard let snapDoc = snapShot?.documents else {
             print("Return  ")
             return
         }
   }
}
```